# How to make Git track file metadata only?

Tags: git, version-control

Is it possible to use Git (or similar software) to track file metadata such as name and location without tracking file contents?

I want to track history of files added or removed from a folder, name changes, ownership changes and similar data.

LFS has been suggested to me but seems like it is not what I'm after.

Comment: `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all` maybe?

Comment: If you want to use Git, I think you need to convert these data to a file first and then track the file.

Comment: Git is a content tracker, not a metadata tracker, so: no. Convert the metadata *to* content (as @ElpieKay said) and Git can track that.